# How can this codebehind be written better?

Tags: asp.net, code-behind

I have a form which has a single textbox that sends some data to the database upon hitting enter. Data is displayed below the textbox in a repeater control. Input data is displayed on the form immediately by binding the data to the repeater in the TextChanged event of that textbox.

In the CodeBehind, I am calling BindRepeater method twice, once on every new page load and once on the TextChanged event of the textbox.

How can this be rewritten to call the BindRepeater only once and still achieve the same effect?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        BindRepeater();
    }
}

protected void BindRepeater()
{
    // data retrieval
    // repeater binding 
}

protected void CreateData(string newdata)
{
    // data insert
}

protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TextBox1.Text != string.Empty)
    {
        string _newData = TextBox1.Text.Trim();
        CreateData(_newData);
        BindRepeater();
    }
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't want to call it from two places? Code looks ok to me!

Comment: Probably belongs over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DavidGouge: Is it normal to do this, even if there might more places where BindRepeater might be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an event that would be fired after the text changed event to do the binding in. you can now remove it from the page load event.

Comment: I am calling it in Page_Load event, so that existing data is displayed upon the first page load.

Comment: It would still be called in the other event

Comment: Sorry, I did not become clear on how to go about doing this. Could you please add some pseudo code?